# Style same class in another element with + selector differently

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

There's a website that has code like I've put on the following jsfiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/roa8k7js/

The site has very complex css styling, over 10,000 lines. In switching this site over to WordPress, the styling was all maintained and everything was put into a theme.

As such, every `<section>` is now inside a wrapper. Because of this, the styling does not function correctly.

The `<section>` padding is determined by a number of rules, including at least one major rule that uses the `+` selector.

The rule looks like this:

```
#layout1 .option-b:not(.custom-bg-image) + .option-b:not(.custom-bg-img)
{
  padding-top: 0;
}
```

Since the wrapper was added, the `+` selector won't correctly identify the pattern:

```
<div class="wrapper1">
  <section class="option-b">This is some text</section>
</div>
<div class="wrapper1">
  <section class="option-b">This is some more text - there shouldn't be any padding on top of this one</section>
</div>
```

```css
section {
  border: 1px solid black;
}

#layout1 .container1>section {
  padding-top: 2em;
  padding-bottom: 2em;
}

#layout1 .option-b:not(.custom-bg-image)+.option-b:not(.custom-bg-img) {
  padding-top: 0;
}

#layout1 .container1>.wrapper1>section {
  padding-top: 2em;
  padding-bottom: 2em;
}
```

```html
<div id="layout1">
  <div class="container1">
    <section class="option-b">This is some text</section>
    <section class="option-b">This is some more text - notice how there isn't a padding top on this one</section>
  </div>
</div>

<div id="layout1">
  <div class="container1">
    <div class="wrapper1">
      <section class="option-b">This is some text</section>
    </div>
    <div class="wrapper1">
      <section class="option-b">This is some more text - there shouldn't be any padding on top of this one</section>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I am trying to determine if there is an easy way to adjust the CSS so that it can correctly identify a `<section>` in the next wrapper to set a value for `top-padding`

Also note, there is no way to remove the wrappers, and all the sections are already styled correctly, without them.

Comment: Hi space, i'm guessing this is your question: *"I am trying to determine if there is an easy way to adjust the css so that it can correctly identify how to adjust section padding to 0 on further instances for the rule as mentioned above (where it is of a particular class and not of another class)."*? If so, can you narrow that down or re-word it. This is all slightly confusing.

Comment: If you look at the jsfiddle, I first have two text blocks that are styled as they are intended. Then there are two textblocks with the wrapper added. They should have the same styling, ideally just by adjusting the one css rule.

Answer (score 0):

The sibling selector can not be used with elements that don't share the same hierarchy. See [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Adjacent_sibling_combinator) for info:

> The adjacent sibling combinator (+) separates two selectors and matches the second element *only if it immediately follows the first element*, and both are children of the same parent element.

Here are a few workarounds (assuming there are only 2 `<section>` per wrapper as your example depicts):

- Give it another class that overrides the padding (by far the easiest)
- Target only the `nth` element
- Javascript

1 ) Just add a "no padding" class to any element you don't want padding added to:

```css
section {
  border: 1px solid black;
}

.wrapper1 > section {
  padding-top: 2em;
  padding-bottom: 2em;
}

.wrapper1 > section.pt-0 {
  padding-top: 0;
}
```

```html
<div id="layout1">
  <div class="container1">
    <div class="wrapper1">
      <section class="option-b">This is some text</section>
    </div>
    <div class="wrapper1">
      <section class="option-b pt-0">This is some more text - there shouldn't be any padding on top of this one</section>
    </div>    
    <div class="wrapper1">
      <section class="option-b pt-0">This is some more text - there shouldn't be any padding on top of this one</section>
    </div>    
    <div class="wrapper1">
      <section class="option-b">This is some text</section>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

2 ) Target the `nth` element

```css
section {
  border: 1px solid black;
}

.wrapper1 > section {
  padding-top: 2em;
  padding-bottom: 2em;
}

.wrapper1:not(:first-child) > section {
  padding-top: 0;
}
```

```html
<div id="layout1">
  <div class="container1">
    <div class="wrapper1">
      <section class="option-b">This is some text</section>
    </div>
    <div class="wrapper1">
      <section class="option-b">This is some more text - there shouldn't be any padding on top of this one</section>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

3) of course javascript:

```js
const elems = document.querySelectorAll('#layout1 .wrapper1 > .option-b:not(.custom-bg-image)');

if (elems.length > 1) elems[1].style.paddingTop = 0;
```

```css
section {
  border: 1px solid black;
}

.wrapper1 > section {
  padding-top: 2em;
  padding-bottom: 2em;
}
```

```html
<div id="layout1">
  <div class="container1">
    <div class="wrapper1">
      <section class="option-b">This is some text</section>
    </div>
    <div class="wrapper1">
      <section class="option-b">This is some more text - there shouldn't be any padding on top of this one</section>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```